# Active Directory stops responding after loosing a domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, domaincontroller

One of my domain controllers corrupted and the secondary DC has not come online since. I have found the following error message in the event log with event ID 1126.

```
Active Directory Domain Services was unable to establish a connection with the global catalog. 
 
Additional Data 
Error value:
1355 The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. 
Internal ID:
3201641 
 
User Action: 
Make sure a global catalog is available in the forest, and is reachable from this domain controller. You may use the nltest utility to diagnose this problem.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the remaining domain controller, edit the registry value at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters\SysvolReady`

It should initially be 0. Set it to 1 and restart Active Directory Domain Services.

Comment: https://www.bursky.net/index.php/2019/07/active-directory-domain-services-unable-establish-connection-with-global-catalog/